# Decompose 2D matrices into mixture of Gaussians

Tags: distributions, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have a 2D array that roughly represents a probability distribution in the 2D space. That is, all values in this 2D matrix sum up to 1. I want to decompose this 2D matrix into a sum of Gaussians. Means represent actual indices in the matrix, while covariances represent the degree of spread of the Guassians. I know the number `k` of Gaussian components that I want. Is there an efficient algorithm to perform this task? I don't want the EM algorithm; it seems too slow.

Comment: I would like to better understand your data.  Are you saying you have something like a 2d-kde that has been normalized, like an empirical surface?  If so then EM will kill you, you would be faster to resample, but there is a crazy-fast way to fix it: least squares on the analytic forms.  As long as you move more sample locations than the total sum of parameters in your system then you should be fine.  Could you provide sample/toy data so I can make a nice answer for this? fwiw, I have had to do this a half-dozen times in real life, and it was very useful.